# Listar filhas de determinada Page

Tags: wordpress, menu

Não estou conseguindo listar as filhas do menu Instituições que é uma Page.

Instituições
   - Policia Militar
   - Prefeitura
   - Secretarias

```
<li><a href="#">Instituições</a>

 <ul>

                <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=Instituições&depth=1”); ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li><a href="#">Instituições</a>
            <?php
                $titleslug = 'Instituições';
                $unsanitized_titleslug = str_replace('-',' ',$titleslug);
                $pageinfo = get_page_by_title($unsanitized_titleslug);
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$pageinfo->ID);?>
            </ul>
        </li>
```